# Python: Function with while loop returns None at the end. How do I remedy this?

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop

I am doing an [exercise from hackerrank.com](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cut-the-sticks).

My main issue with my code is my function returns none with my while loop.

I know I can pass the exercise by not using it as a function but my personal goal is to maintain it as one. Is there a way I can keep my code as a function and not return None?

**My Code**

```
def cutOperation(sticks):
    currentLine = sticks
    while len(currentLine) != 0:
        newLine = []
        print len(currentLine)
        for stick in currentLine:
            if stick - min(currentLine) != 0:
                newLine.append(stick - min(currentLine))
        currentLine = newLine

_ = int(raw_input().strip())
sticks = map(int,raw_input().strip().split(' '))
#First Test Case for sticks = 5 4 4 2 2 8

print cutOperation(sticks)
```

**Result after running code**

```
6
4
2
1
None
#How do I not return none?
```

Comment: Uh, `return` something explicitly?

Comment: putting `return ''` at the end of your function definition will make nothing print there

Comment: Just call the function and don't `print` it, e.g. `cutOperation(sticks)`

Answer (score 0):

Like others have mentioned in the comments above, you can add a return statement and return whatever you want for your function.  Python by default returns `None` for functions that don't specify a return statement.

If you just don't want to print None for this exercise though, you can simply change:

```
print cutOperation(sticks)
```

to

```
cutOperation(sticks)
```

since your last line is printing the return of the `cutOperation` function.